# Dynamic Query Builder with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

i want to create an query builder to generate report query dynamically

assume that we have something like this in DB to store Tasks

[image]

i write this method in my repository

```
    public IQueryable<T> fnExecute<T>(params Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] perdicates) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            IQueryable<T> queryable = Context.Set<T>();
            foreach (var clause in perdicates)
            {
                queryable = queryable.Where(clause);
            }

            return queryable;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            fnLogExceptions(exp);
        }
        return null;

    }
```

well in the code u can easily use something like this

```
        var result  = fnExecute<DB.TestTable>(
            s=>s.Id < 113,
            s=>s.LastName.Contains("txtFoo")
            );
```

and what i want to do is : in each task i read the EntityName in DB
and create the predicates by its operators ^_^

here is the problem :

is there anyway that i can invoke my method by set the T type dynamically at run time and generate predicate Expressions dynamically by entity Property Name.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection + Expression methods. Example:

```
Type t = typeof(DB.TestTable);
var s = Expression.Parameter(t, "s");
var l1 = Expression.Lambda(
    typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(t, typeof(bool)),
    Expression.LessThan(
        Expression.PropertyOrField(s, "Id"), 
        Expression.Constant(113)
    ),
    s
);

var query = repo.GetType()
    .GetMethod("fnExecute")
    .MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(repo, new object[] {l1});
```

It should give you equivalent of:

```
var query = fnExecute<DB.TestTable>(s=>s.Id < 113);
```